# Angular Kendo Grid Row on hover effect

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to change the row's background when the user hovers over them (useful help, row tracking).

I tried to apply a CSS class (`<class>:hover`) to every row using `[rowClass]`, which works in theory, but the style won't get applied.

`<kendo-grid [rowClass]="rowCallback" [data]="gridData" [height]="410">`
...

```
export class AppComponent {
    public gridData: any[] = products;

    rowCallback(context) {
      return 'styler';
    }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-hover-color-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward approach would be to target the hovered rows via CSS and add the desired styling, e.g.:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [`
  .k-grid tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`]
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1md8l?file=app/app.component.ts)